# Returning the first index of an element in a vector in C++

Tags: python, c++, vector, indexing

I am trying to find the first index of an element in a vector in c++.

Let's say you have a vector: [2, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 1, 2, 6, 3].

I would like to find the position of the number 6.

So the first time the number 6 occurs is at an index value of 4.

Is there a function that can do that in C++?

I know in Python, I can use the list.index(n) method to do that for me.

Answer (score 12):

```
std::vector<int> vct;
//insert value

//use std::find to get iterator
auto itr=std::find(vct.begin(), vct.end(), 6);
if(itr==vct.end())
    return;
auto index=std::distance(vct.begin(), itr);
```

Comment: Just as an aside, I would mention that to use the `auto` keyword, I believe that you have to make sure that C++11 features are in effect when compiling.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to do something like this:

```
int getIndexOf(std::vector<int> v, int num)
{
    for(std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != v.size(); i++)
    {
        if(v[i] == num)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

---

**EDIT**: As efficiency is definitely a consideration, perhaps this may be a viable solution. I am storing the index of each item from the vector into its corresponding hashed value in an [unordered_multimap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_multimap/). Note: this is assuming the vector will not have its contents changing *super* frequently.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::unordered_multimap<int,int>::const_iterator IntMapIterator;
typedef std::pair<int,int> IntPair;

std::unordered_multimap<int,int> hashValues(const std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    std::unordered_multimap<int,int> hashedValues;
    for(std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != vec.size(); i++)
    {
        hashedValues.emplace(vec[i], i);
    }
    return hashedValues;
}

struct IntPairComparator
{
    bool operator()(const IntPair& left, const IntPair& right) const
    {
        return left.second < right.second;
    }
};

int getEarliestIndex(const std::unordered_multimap<int,int>& hashedValues, int num)
{
    std::pair<IntMapIterator,IntMapIterator> range = hashedValues.equal_range(num);
    IntPair minPair = *std::min_element(range.first, range.second, IntPairComparator());
    return minPair.second;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> bigVector;
    // do stuff and fill contents of vector
    std::unordered_multimap<int,int>& hashedValues = hashValues(bigVector);
    int earliestIndex = getEarliestIndex(hashedValues, 6);
}
```

Comment: so basically, i need to go through my vector and stop at the position where the vector's element equals the number that i want?

Comment: Aye. Although, if efficiency is a problem and you can do some pre-processing, I suppose an alternative would be to hash the value of each item in the vector and store the corresponding index into a HashMap.

Comment: This is a brute-force way of doing it, but yes, it works. It is essentially what std::find does behind the scenes, but it uses iterators rather than array indices (although with std::vector, the iterator may well be handled the same way as you have here).

Comment: Updated my answer with that alternative solution I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
InputIterator find (InputIterator beg, InputIterator end, const T& value)
```

which is defined in `#include <algorithm>`.

### Usage

Say you have the following vector:

```
std::vector<int> numberVector;
    
numberVector.push_back(1);
numberVector.push_back(2);
numberVector.push_back(3);
numberVector.push_back(4);
numberVector.push_back(5);
```

You could find index of `4` by:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator position = std::find(
    numberVector.begin(), numberVector.end(), 4
);
```

Then check whether it's found:

```
bool exists = (position != numberVector.end());
```

If it exists, then you could get the index by:

```
int index = position - numbVector.begin();
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use this, if your vector is not very large..

`std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), item)!=vector.end()`
You will directly get the iterator pointing to that value..

in case you vector is too large, you can some [binary_search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search), [lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound), or [upper_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) algorithms, because using this for huge vectors impact performance..

Comment: my vector will have upwards of 1 million elements. Is that large?

Comment: except, my loop will only go up to the sqrt of the length of the vector

Comment: binary_search, lower_bound, and upper_bound are really only useful if your data is sorted. For data that is not in any particular sort order, std::find is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no explicit function that can do this but what #51k has pointed in the right direction. You might have to write your own implementation if you have a need, other have mentioned some of those

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Geoffrey Tucker's response, you can actually generalize to a template function as such:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template <typename T=int, class ContainerType=std::vector<T> >
typename std::iterator_traits<typename ContainerType::iterator>::difference_type
get_index_of(const ContainerType& c, const T& t) {
  ContainerType::const_iterator itr = std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), t);
  return (std::distance(c.begin(), itr));
}
```

Note that here, the index returned for an item not in the container is actually past the value of `c.size()`, where `c` is the container (in your case, a vector). This differs from Geoffrey's implementation where he returns -1; here, we leave it up to the container type to determine what the return type of the function will be.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int find_index( int n, vector<int> & v )
{
  int pos = 0;
  for( const auto i : v ) { if( i == n ) return pos; ++pos; }
  return -1; // not found index
}

int main()
{
  vector<int> v{ 2, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 1, 2, 6, 3 };
  cout << find_index( 6, v ) << endl;
}
```